# How to choose which schema design for a tree structured domain model

Tags: c#, schema, mongodb

I have the following classes that I want to store.

```
public class StorableObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : StorableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Project : StorableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task : StorableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Timesheet> TimeSheets { get; set; }
}

public class Timesheet : StorableObject
{
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Schema design has a lot to do with which queries you'll be needing, so let me try to explain a bit. I'll need to do fast queries to extract:

- all Tasks on a Project
- all Timesheets on a Task
- all Projects a user owns
- all Tasks a user owns
- all Timesheets a user owns.

I also need some summations like get total time spent on a Project or Task in a given time period and total time spend per user in a given period. (MapReduse I suppose)

I started out (after reading [this blog](http://seanhess.github.io/2012/02/01/mongodb_relational.html)) with 4 collections (Users, Projects, Tasks, Timesheets), each child would have a [parent reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) so I could construct my domain model in my business logic.

However after watching [this](http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http://blip.tv/mongodb/schema-design-with-mongodb-3723187&h=9AQH47zlj) I've changed my mind and now going for a more embedded approach.

```
{
   _id: 123456789,
   owner_id: 123,
   name: "My Project",
   tasks: [
            {
               owner_id: 123,
               name: "My Task",
               timesheets: [
                             {
                                owner_id: 123,
                                ...
                             }
                           ]
            }
          ]
}
```

What's your take? Is that a fast schema design?